# imagemagick validation and comparison of images

Tags: testing, imagemagick

I have to compare a .tiff and .pdf images, can anyone help me with the commands of imagemagick tool.i want to compare the image quality parameters like resolution,size,pixel.

I want to check if two different format images are equal or not?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried ImageMagick's [`identify`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) utility?

Comment: "identify  imageName " command is giving me the details of a particular file only, not comparing with the other file

Comment: How equal is "equal"?  Are you looking for an exact match (i.e. every pixel should be the same value in both the tiff and the pdf)?  Or are you just trying to see if the two images are similar enough to be considered visually the same?  Lossy compression algorithms are going to create artifacting that makes the images different at the pixel level.